# Kubernetes - is there a repository for centos that works?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Kubernetes - is there a repository for centos that works? I don't want to use git clone, I would prefer to use rpm packages. Is this package compatible with the new docker 17-0XX if it exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use below repo to install the kubernetes rpm in **CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)**

**add this repo**

```
cat <<EOF > /etc/yum.repos.d/kubernetes.repo
[kubernetes]
name=Kubernetes
baseurl=http://yum.kubernetes.io/repos/kubernetes-el7-x86_64
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
repo_gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/yum-key.gpg
        https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/rpm-package-key.gpg
EOF
```

Use this command to install

```
yum install -y kubelet kubectl kubernetes-cni kubeadm
```

my docker version.

```
Server:
 Version:         1.12.6
 API version:     1.24
 Package version: docker-1.12.6-32.git88a4867.el7.centos.x86_64
```